# web2py - my application doesn' login

Tags: python, web2py

i have a web2py application and am using default/user/login to login to my application  but sometimes when i login the application redirect to the login page agin and sometimes the system logged fine and there is no problem i dont know why ?

so please can anyone tell me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to day without mode details. Do you use the user action or your own login action? If you bring this up on the web2py list we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something like this happen with cookie based load balancing. The cookie was being set too late, so the user would switch frontends sometimes when they logged it.

If you have a load balancer over 2 frontends, you might see this happen 50% of the time.

Check the logs and make sure the hits are all going to the same frontend.